# sails-auth user table has no password field but still validates

Tags: sails.js, passport-local

I just started working with sails-auth and running it from MySql. I see that the user table it automatically generated doesn't have a password field. Odd. I track down the register(?) method and see that it even deletes the password property before creating the user. So I figure that when you Post to auth/local and give it an email and password that it just checks the email exists and ignores the password (leaving it to the user to tweak this later). But when I login and enter a bad password it won't let me. I have to enter a valid password. How does it know what a valid password is when there is no password in the user table??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User has 1-n relationship with [Passport](https://github.com/trailsjs/sails-auth/blob/master/api/models/Passport.js#L56) model, which contains password field

Usually <del>Ideally</del>, credentials are stored in 1-n relationship with User model, when user can login via various methods e.g. password, OAuth etc.